# Are repr and str always identical on Pythons builtin numeric types?

Tags: python, representation

Are `repr` and `str` identical on Pythons built-in numeric types (`int`, `bool`, `float`, and `complex`), or are there (esoteric?) situations where the two may yield different results?

Related questions on SO (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/974555)) focus on how `__repr__` and `__str__` may be implemented differently, and return different values for strings, but I can't find anything on the actual implementation on numbers.

Comment: The question was closed as being a duplicate, but the linked post does not answer my question, which is specifically about the `__repr__` and `__str__` methods on `int`, `bool`, `float`, and `complex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary source of information on this is http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects
For example, in `boolobject.c`:

```
PyTypeObject PyBool_Type = {
    ...stuff...

    bool_repr,                                  /* tp_repr */

    ...stuff...

    bool_repr,                                  /* tp_str */
```

so yes, they're guaranteed to be the same.

For floats, `float_repr` is different from `float_str` and depends on `sys.float_repr_style`.